# LaserJet prints half of all pages pink?

Tags: printing, printer, laser-printer, hp-laserjet

I have an HP Color LaserJet CM1015 MFP printer that's been in storage over a year. It worked perfectly before putting it in storage, but since I took it out it's practically unusable, since it prints random colors onto the pages as you can see in this photo.

[image]

This is what it looked like when I opened it up:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1st Solution**

In order to isolate the defect to the formatter or print engine, load plain letter paper in tray 2 and press the "Engine Test" button.  There is a small circular hole in the back of the printer, use a tooth pick to depress the button that is on the DC Controller PCB.

If the page that comes out has magenta toner all over it, then there is a problem with the lower High Voltage Power Supply PCB.

If the page that comes out does not have the magenta toner all over it, then the formatter/ICB connections should be inspected/reseated.  There is an FFC between the DCC and ICB that needs to be inspected and reseated.

**2nd Solution** 
the issue was the formatter connection to the dc controller. On your printer there is interconnet board. I would just remove the formatter with the power off and reinsert and see if that helps. The other item is to go into diagnostics menu and choose the item disable cartridge check. Now remove the magenta toner and run sheets again to see if the issue is still present but with a different color. It is possible one of the other color toners is causing the issue and this mode allows you to remove, switch around and do whatever you want with the toners to try and narrow down the issue. Also make sure the user did replace the toner. Can not tell you how many times the user says they replaced when in fact it was never done. Good Luck.

**Final Solution** 
The color toner cartridge needs to be replaced and odds are the issue will be gone.

Comment: Thanks @Ragesh. It looks like I need to replace my toner cartridges. Using some of your keywords I was able to refine my google search and came upon this troubleshooting page specific to my printer.

Comment: http://h20566.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/kb/docDisplay?javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.prp_ba847bafb2a2d782fcbb0710b053ce01=wsrp-navigationalState%3DdocId%253Demr_na-c00782118-5%257CdocLocale%253D%257CcalledBy%253D&javax.portlet.tpst=ba847bafb2a2d782fcbb0710b053ce01&ac.admitted=1390202350391.876444892.199480143

Comment: Also, after some confusion, I found "Engine Test" button was located behind a faceplate that I had to remove a small screw for on the back of the printer. It exposed a small part of a circuit board with a tiny push button that when pushed printed a test page with lines. Thanks again for your attention!

Comment: OK. Up vote my answer if u like it

Comment: Says I need 15 points to upvote. I have 13. How do I get a couple of points around here?